# Interpolation between curves

Tags: interpolation

I am trying to do a 2D interpolation between two curves as you can see from the attached picture.
[image]

where $a$ is a varrying paramter. $f_{a_1}$ and $f_{a_2}$ are known, or at least I can perform interpolation along them. The desired point is $(x_{des},y_{a_{des}}(x_{des}))$. Hence, I think I will have to do three interpolations as follows:

1. Interpolate along $f_{a_1} $
2. Interpolate along $f_{a_2}$
3. Interpolate between the results to get $f_{a_{des}}$

However, I am not trusting the outcome. Does any one have a suggestion?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those blue and red curves given as a set of points?

Comment: @Misery , yes, they are given as a set of points

Comment: I would suggest using kernel interpolation (estimation) treating all points (for both curves) as one set. See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) and this [free e-book](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)

Comment: It is not clear what makes $x_{des}, y_{des}$ special in your sketch. If you are just looking for something in between two functions,  you could take the average of their $y$-values. Apparently you need something more sophisticated than that, but since the objective is unstated, it's impossible to tell what would meet it.